# Contacs does not save correctly when saving them to vcf file in Android 7

Tags: java, android

I have a code and it does not save contacts consistently. Each time I create csv file the file size is different and so the number of lines contained in the file. It doesn't makes a good backup on Android 7 only. I am using emulator with Android 7 and I have also tested the same code on Android 5.1 physical device and it seems to do everything right with exact same file size every time. Only problem is with Android 7, it makes file sometimes smaller and sometimes larger. Here is the code used to make backup of contacts:

```
 public void get(Cursor cursor) {
        //cursor.moveToFirst();
        String lookupKey = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY));
        Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_VCARD_URI, lookupKey);
        AssetFileDescriptor fd;
        try {
            fd = this.getContentResolver().openAssetFileDescriptor(uri, "r");
            FileInputStream fis = fd.createInputStream();
            byte[] buf;

            if (fd.getDeclaredLength() != AssetFileDescriptor.UNKNOWN_LENGTH) {
                buf = new byte[(int) fd.getDeclaredLength()];
            } else {
                buf = new byte[fis.available()];
            }

            fis.read(buf);
            String vcardstring = new String(buf);
            vCard.add(vcardstring);

            mFileOutputStream.write(vcardstring.toString().getBytes());

        } catch (Exception e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean by "does not save contacts consistently"? Are you looking for a guarenteed max file size?

Comment: @10101010 I mean each time backup has different file size of same contacts.

Comment: I think these might be cause they are different versions of vCard..
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VCard
Can you verify this by checking the contents of the string?
One solution is to use  library to convert versions of vCard format.. maybe this?
https://github.com/mangstadt/ez-vcard